# How to save specific api repsonse to a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm making an app with the https://calendarific.com api. Basically my app so far allows you to click a country and it returns only the first holiday for the country. I want to return all the holidays for the month we are in currently.

My problem is I can't save the the api date result to a variable.

When I try to do something like this:

```
let holidayMonth = data.response.holidays.date.datetime.month;
```

I get "Cannot read property 'datetime' of undefined".

Although when i do this:

```
let holidayMonth = data.response.holidays[0].date.datetime.month;
```

it works. How can I save all the api date results to one variable?

Comment: Loop through the `holidays` array and save each of them in an array.

Comment: You can specify the month with a parameter to the API, you don't need to read it out of the result.

Comment: Just save the whole `data.response.holidays` array in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array and get all the months.

```
let holidayMonths = data.response.holidays.map(h => h.date.datetime.month);
```

Comment: I get a console error `Cannot read property 'holidays' of undefined`

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(data.response)` in the question?

Comment: There are hundreds of results in the array so here is the first one.            `holidays: Array(118)
[0 … 99]
0:
country: {id: "ca", name: "Canada"}
date:
datetime: {year: 2020, month: 1, day: 1}
iso: "2020-01-01"
__proto__: Object
description: "New Year's Day is the first day of a new year according to the Gregorian calendar used in Canada and many other countries."
locations: "All"
name: "New Year's Day"
states: "All"
type: ["National holiday"]`

Comment: Never mind, I had a typo: `reponse` should be `response`